# Azure website and Git commit id

Tags: git, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to find the id of the commit used in an automated git deployment to an Azure website?

Particularly, after that deployment has been swapped in to another deployment slot (which is NOT configured for auto-git deployment).

EDIT: Preferably a programmatic way, but visible in either portal would be a good start.

Comment: Can you clarify a few things? 1 What portal are you using? 2 Are you referring to Local Git (as opposed to GitHub integration?) 3 How are you looking for it to be exposed? Environment Variable or Just visible for Operations Purposes?

Comment: BitBucket integration. I'd like to see it in the footer of my website. I've just tried showing the datetime of the website assembly, but it just returns year 1601.

Comment: The root problem I'm trying to solve is - what changes have been made since the last accepted build that was swapped in to the production slot.

Answer (score 4):

sending a request to
`https://<yourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments`

should get you an array of objects that look like this

```
{
  "id":"3a706bb8f1e39b1f01f1911c1440d31077c90e8e",
  "status":4,
  "status_text":"",
  "author_email":"name@example.com",
  "author":"FistName LastName",
  "deployer":"userName",
  "message":"Site updated: 2015-02-12 00:00:00",
  "progress":"",
  "received_time":"2015-02-12T00:00:00Z",
  "start_time":"2015-02-12T00:00:00Z",
  "end_time":"2015-02-12T00:00:00Z",
  "last_success_end_time":"2015-02-12T00:00:00Z",
  "complete":true,
  "active":true,
  "is_temp":false,
  "is_readonly":false,
  "url":"https://<yourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/3a706bb8f1e39b1f01f1911c1440d31077c90e8e",
  "log_url":"https://<yourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/3a706bb8f1e39b1f01f1911c1440d31077c90e8e/log",
  "site_name":"yourSiteName"
}
```

with `"id"` being the commit id that was used for a deployment.

Comment: Thanks ahmelsayed. This works for slots not configured for git-deployment, which is exactly what I need. Do you know if there's a way to fetch more records, maybe via query string?

Comment: you can see all the [routes here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/master/Kudu.Services.Web/App_Start/NinjectServices.cs#L393-L398) and the [controller is here for example](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/master/Kudu.Services/Deployment/DeploymentController.cs#L144-L166) you can query more details about a deployment (like the logs, etc) if you add the id in the url

Comment: `/api/deployments/{id}/log` for example.

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't want to call the API, you could do this with a [Post Deployment Action Hook](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks).

running a commit like this will get you the hash:

```
git log -1 | sed -n '/commit/p'
```

You will need to figure out how you'd want to store it in order to access it. Options include environment variable or text file.

Comment: Thanks SyntaxC4. ahmelsayed's answer got me what I needed today, but this hook I think we will use for a number of other things - great tip.